# The Moduli Space of Gauge Theory

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Physicists often speak of "Connections modulo gauge transformations" as the natural configuration space of a gauge field. In this sense, the fundamental object of study in gauge theory is the space of pairs,

$$\frac{(E,\nabla)}{\text{gauge transformations}}$$

Where $E$ is a complex vector bundle, and $\nabla$ is a suitable connection. In the case of gauge group $U(1)$ and line bundle $E=L$, there is a natural identification of this configuration space with the set of holomorphic structures on $L$, i.e.,

$$\frac{(L,\nabla)}{\text{gauge transformations}}\cong \text{Pic}^0(X)$$

Where the zero is there because there are no magnetic monopoles in nature.

> This is immensely useful, because the space on the RHS is amazingly
>   concrete and visualizable, computable, etc...

The question is, does this correspondence continue for bundles of rank higher than one, and general compact gauge group $G$ (i.e. interpretation as holomorphic structures)? This would allow for a similar analysis of general Yang-Mills theory, and other non-abelian gauge theories of the Standard Model.

Also, does anyone have references for these results?

Comment: Does [Donaldson's theorem](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-50/1/1.full.pdf) help? Note also that he has a theorem that the moduli space of irreducible ASD connections on an $SU(2)$ bundle over a compact Kahler surface is the same (as sets) as the isomorphism classes of stable holomorphic rank 2 bundles. I believe this should have extensions to $SU(n)$ but do not currently remember a reference.

Comment: You might find the discussion in Chapter 5 of [this review article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157391901175) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of $U(n)$, the correspondence continues for higher dimensional complex vector bundles. See page 3 of http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/YM-lectures/lecture10.pdf for details.

Comment: I failed to say in my original comment that the extension to all bundles over arbitrary manifolds is known as the Uhlenbeck-Yau theorem. The version in your link is specifically for Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Ahh very sorry about that - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: No need to apologize, I just wanted to clarify if it wasn't clear!